# Best option to fuzz a C Network Program

Tags: penetration-test, c, fuzzing

I have a client/server simple program in C. I want to test the server running on different machine with random inputs. I have looked at 'Bunny-the-fuzzer' but from what I can understand It wont be much help when the target program/application is on remote machine.

Can someone recommend me any other available tools for testing such network programs ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might be too heavy for your use case, but Sulley https://github.com/OpenRCE/sulley is a good framework.